# Sync specific photo album between devices

Tags: macbook-pro, iphone, itunes, icloud, photos

I don't want to sync all all my iPhone photos on my MacBook because it's going to use too much space.

However, I do want to sync specific albums. Let's say I'd want to sync `Favorites` and `Test`.

How can I do that?

---

I didn't sync my iPhone with my mac for a long time because I'm afraid some of the photos will be deleted either from my iPhone or from my MacBook.

Comment: What versions of macOS, iTunes and iOS are you running?

Comment: @Monomeeth `macOS Sierra 10.12.3` and `iOS 10.2.1`.